# Did not get my string printout for ASCII number =7

Tags: c++

my 4-byte data contain ASCII decimal number 7,0,0,0, as shown as follows. 
at address [20] data `c[0][20] =7, c[0][21] =0, c[0][22] =0, c[0][23] =0`

I do not why I can get any output by `printf(" s= %s\t\n", s.c_str());`. but i can get output 7 with `printf(" s= %d\t\n", (int)c[0][20]);`
 what is the proper way to get all 4-byte printout?

```
    const char * c[3];       
    char cs[5];
    memcpy(cs, c[0] + 20, 4);
    string s (cs,4);
    printf(" s= %s\t\n", s.c_str());
    printf(" s= %d\t\n", (int)c[0][20]);
```

Comment: Do `c[0]` point to a string of at least 24 characters?

Comment: And by the way you can skip the temporary `cs` variable and `memcpy`, and do just plain `string s(c[0] + 20, 4);` And why do you use the type-unsafe `printf` function to print?

Comment: ASCII 7 would be bell character - it's not printable.

Comment: In ASCII, that would be `BEL`, `NUL`, `NUL`, `NUL`; none of which is a printable character. (This kind of thing usually happens when confusing numbers with digits.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
printf(" s =");
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    printf(" %d ", (int)c[0][20+i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try.

```
for (size_t z = 0; z < 4; z++)
{
    printf("element %zu is %c\n", z, c[z]);
}
```

to verify that the values are what you think they are.

ASCII 7 is the bell character, which might make a tone of some sort when you print it.

[See](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Comment: it is the standard format for printing a size_t variable